# WPF: binding a flag with checkboxes

Tags: wpf, binding

I wrote this enum (**flag**):

```
using System;
namespace AndreyBushman.AutoCAD {
    // Specifies, how and when .NET application will load. 
    // It is a flag.
    [Flags]
    public enum LoadCtrls {
        // Load application upon detection of proxy object
        AtProxyFound = 1,
        // Load the application at startup
        AtAutoCADStart = 2,
        // Load the application at start of a command
        AtCommandStart = 4,
        // Load the application at the request of a user 
        // or another application
        AtUserOrApplicationRequirement = 8,
        // Do not load the application
        NotLoad = 16,
        // Load the application transparently
        TransparencyLoad = 32,
    }
}
```

Now I have created `StackPanel` with `CheckBox` items:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stackAllUsersLoadCtrls">
    <CheckBox Margin="2">At proxy found</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Margin="2">At AutoCAD start</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Margin="2">At command start</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Margin="2">At user or application requirement</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Margin="2">Not load</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Margin="2">Transparency load</CheckBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Result screen:

[image]

How can I bind instance of `LoadCtrls` (it is a **flag**) with `CheckBox` items?

**UPD**
I have rewritten my code (added wrapper, rewrote converter, and XAML):

Wrapper:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ab = AndreyBushman.AutoCAD;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace AcadLoadManaged {

    public sealed class LoadCtrlsWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        ab.LoadCtrls loadCtrls;

        public ab.LoadCtrls GetloadCtrls() {
            return loadCtrls;
        }
        public LoadCtrlsWrapper() {
            loadCtrls = default(ab.LoadCtrls);
        }
        public LoadCtrlsWrapper(ab.LoadCtrls loadCtrls) {
            this.loadCtrls = loadCtrls;
        }

        public Boolean AtAutoCADStart {
            get {
                return (loadCtrls & ab.LoadCtrls.AtAutoCADStart) != 0;
            }
            set {
                if (value)
                    loadCtrls |= ab.LoadCtrls.AtAutoCADStart;
                else
                    loadCtrls &= ~ab.LoadCtrls.AtAutoCADStart;
                OnPropertyChanged("AtAutoCADStart");
            }
        }

        public Boolean AtCommandStart {
            get {
                return (loadCtrls & ab.LoadCtrls.AtCommandStart) != 0;
            }
            set {
                if (value)
                    loadCtrls |= ab.LoadCtrls.AtCommandStart;
                else
                    loadCtrls &= ~ab.LoadCtrls.AtCommandStart;
                OnPropertyChanged("AtCommandStart");
            }
        }

        public Boolean AtProxyFound {
            get {
                return (loadCtrls & ab.LoadCtrls.AtProxyFound) != 0;
            }
            set {
                if (value)
                    loadCtrls |= ab.LoadCtrls.AtProxyFound;
                else
                    loadCtrls &= ~ab.LoadCtrls.AtProxyFound;
                OnPropertyChanged("AtProxyFound");
            }
        }

        public Boolean AtUserOrApplicationRequirement {
            get {
                return (loadCtrls & ab.LoadCtrls.AtUserOrApplicationRequirement) != 0;
            }
            set {
                if (value)
                    loadCtrls |= ab.LoadCtrls.AtUserOrApplicationRequirement;
                else
                    loadCtrls &= ~ab.LoadCtrls.AtUserOrApplicationRequirement;
                OnPropertyChanged("AtUserOrApplicationRequirement");
            }
        }

        public Boolean NotLoad {
            get {
                return (loadCtrls & ab.LoadCtrls.NotLoad) != 0;
            }
            set {
                if (value)
                    loadCtrls |= ab.LoadCtrls.NotLoad;
                else
                    loadCtrls &= ~ab.LoadCtrls.NotLoad;
                OnPropertyChanged("NotLoad");
            }
        }

        public Boolean TransparencyLoad {
            get {
                return (loadCtrls & ab.LoadCtrls.TransparencyLoad) != 0;
            }
            set {
                if (value)
                    loadCtrls |= ab.LoadCtrls.TransparencyLoad;
                else
                    loadCtrls &= ~ab.LoadCtrls.TransparencyLoad;
                OnPropertyChanged("TransparencyLoad");
            }
        }

        void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName) {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler temp = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != temp)
                temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Converter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Data;
using ab = AndreyBushman.AutoCAD;

namespace AcadLoadManaged {

    public sealed class LoadCtrlsConverter : IValueConverter {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            ab.LoadCtrls x = (ab.LoadCtrls)value;
            return new LoadCtrlsWrapper(x);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            LoadCtrlsWrapper x = (LoadCtrlsWrapper)value;
            return x.GetloadCtrls();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<GroupBox Grid.Row="4" Header="Load this plugin, when...:" Grid.Column="0" 
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Padding="3">
    <GroupBox.DataContext>
        <Binding ElementName="lstAllUsers" Path="SelectedItem.LoadCtrls" Mode="TwoWay">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <local:LoadCtrlsConverter/>
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </GroupBox.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Margin="2" Content="At proxy found" IsChecked="{Binding Path=AtProxyFound}"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="2" Content="At AutoCAD start" IsChecked="{Binding Path=AtAutoCADStart}"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="2" Content="At command start" IsChecked="{Binding Path=AtCommandStart}"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="2" Content="At user or application requirement" 
                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=AtUserOrApplicationRequirement}"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="2" Content="Not load" IsChecked="{Binding Path=NotLoad}"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="2" Content="Transparency load" IsChecked="{Binding Path=TransparencyLoad}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

But my binding works only one way. If I modify `CheckBox` values - they don't save. I have tried breakpoint on `ConvertBack` method, but it is not happening. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Had similar needs, here is my approach of TwoWay flags binding.
No hardcoded enum types or any sort of values. Simply set the TargetType and Flags. Brilliant for settings window.

Usage:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=flagsCtrl, Path=Flags, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<local:FlagsControl x:Name="flagsCtrl" TargetType="{x:Type local:TestFlags}" SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
```

FlagsControl:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace FlagsControlDemoApplication
{
    public class FlagsControl : ItemsControl
    {
        public FlagsControl()
        {
            DataProvider = new ObservableCollection<Model>();

            Loaded += OnControlLoaded;
        }

        private void OnControlLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Loaded -= OnControlLoaded;

            Binding isCheckedBinding = new Binding();
            isCheckedBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(Model.IsCheckedProperty);
            isCheckedBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            isCheckedBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

            Binding nameBinding = new Binding();
            nameBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(Model.NameProperty);
            nameBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            nameBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

            var checkBoxFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
            checkBoxFactory.SetValue(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, isCheckedBinding);
            checkBoxFactory.SetValue(CheckBox.ContentProperty, nameBinding);
            checkBoxFactory.AddHandler(CheckBox.CheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnCheckBoxChecked));
            checkBoxFactory.AddHandler(CheckBox.UncheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnCheckBoxUnchecked));

            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CheckBox));
            ItemTemplate.VisualTree = checkBoxFactory;
            ItemsSource = DataProvider;
        }

        public FlagSelectionMode SelectionMode
        {
            get { return (FlagSelectionMode)GetValue(SelectionModeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectionModeProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionModeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SelectionMode), typeof(FlagSelectionMode), typeof(FlagsControl), new PropertyMetadata(FlagSelectionMode.Multiple));

        public ObservableCollection<Model> DataProvider
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<Model>)GetValue(DataProviderProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataProviderProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProviderProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(DataProvider), typeof(ObservableCollection<Model>), typeof(FlagsControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public uint Flags
        {
            get { return (uint)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Flags), typeof(uint), typeof(FlagsControl), new PropertyMetadata(OnValuePropertyChanged));

        private static void OnValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var model in ((FlagsControl)d).DataProvider)
            {
                var val = (uint)Convert.ChangeType(e.NewValue, typeof(uint));

                if (Exists(val, model.Value) != model.IsChecked)
                {
                    model.IsChecked = !model.IsChecked;
                }
            }
        }

        public Type TargetType
        {
            get { return (Type)GetValue(TargetTypeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TargetTypeProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetTypeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(TargetType), typeof(Type), typeof(FlagsControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTargetTypePropertyChanged)));

        private static void OnTargetTypePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var provider = ((FlagsControl)d).DataProvider;

            FieldInfo[] fields = ((Type)e.NewValue).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

            provider.Clear();

            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                var fieldValue = (uint)Convert.ChangeType(field.GetValue(null), typeof(uint));

                provider.Add(new Model() { Name = field.Name, IsChecked = Exists(((FlagsControl)d).Flags, fieldValue), Value = fieldValue });
            }

            ((FlagsControl)d).DataProvider = provider;
        }

        private void OnCheckBoxChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (SelectionMode == FlagSelectionMode.Multiple)
                Flags = Add(Flags, ((Model)((CheckBox)sender).DataContext).Value);
            else Flags = ((Model)((CheckBox)sender).DataContext).Value;
        }
        private void OnCheckBoxUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Flags = Remove(Flags, ((Model)((CheckBox)sender).DataContext).Value);
        }

        public static bool Exists(uint flags, uint flag) => (flags & flag) == flag;
        public static uint Add(uint flags, uint flag) => flags |= flag;
        public static uint Remove(uint flags, uint flag) => Exists(flags, flag) ? flags ^ flag : flags;
    }

    public enum FlagSelectionMode
    {
        Multiple, Single
    }

    public class Model : DependencyObject
    {
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsChecked), typeof(bool), typeof(Model));

        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Name), typeof(string), typeof(Model));

        public uint Value
        {
            get { return (uint)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Value), typeof(uint), typeof(Model));
    }
}
```

[DemoApp & SourceCode](http://1drv.ms/1MvGWD6)

Comment: Hello, seems that if you have 2 FlagControls in the page, it binds only to a Itemsource (I see the same items for both flag controls)

Comment: Fixed! Thx for reporting!

Comment: your wellcome, can you please tell me why the ObservableCollection is shared between the controls is not re-created?

Comment: @advapi - because DataProvider was instantiated only once inside the static dependency property (@see - PropertyMetadata)

Comment: just a stupid question, is there a way I can keep the enum declaration property? Sometime my last element which is "Altro" goes firtst but in my view it's not acceptable since it has a TextBox after it

Answer (score 0):

To adapt a `Model`(LoadCtrls) to a `View`(XAML), use a `ViewModel`.

```
public class ApplicationSettingsViewModel :
    MyViewModelBaseImplementingINotifyPropertyChanged {

    public ApplicationSettingsViewModel(ApplicationSettings model)
    {
      m_model = model;
      m_model.PropertyChanged += OnModelPropertyChanged;
    }

    ... OnModelPropertyChanged(object sender, WhateverArgs e)
    {
      switch(e.PropertyName)
      {
        ...
        case "Load":
          RaisePropertyChanged("IsAtProxyFoundSet");
          RaisePropertyChanged("IsAtAutoCADStartSet");
          ...
          break;
        ...
      }
    }

    ...
    public bool IsAtProxyFoundSet
    {
       get { return m_model.Load & LoadCtrls.AtProxyFound; }
       set { m_model.Load |= LoadCtrls.AtProxyFound; }
    }

    public bool IsAtAutoCADStartSet
    {
       get { return m_model.Load & LoadCtrls.AtAutoCADStart; }
       set { m_model.Load |= LoadCtrls.AtAutoCADStart; }
    }

    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is an updated example :

```
public sealed class UserWrapper {

    private User m_user;

    public UserWrapper(User user) {
        m_user = user;
    }

    public Boolean AtAutoCADStart {
        get {
            return (m_user.loadCtrls & ab.LoadCtrls.AtAutoCADStart) != 0;
        }
        set {
            if (value)
                m_user.loadCtrls |= ab.LoadCtrls.AtAutoCADStart;
            else
                m_user.loadCtrls &= ~ab.LoadCtrls.AtAutoCADStart;
        }
    }

    public Boolean AtCommandStart {
        get {
            return (m_user.loadCtrls & ab.LoadCtrls.AtCommandStart) != 0;
        }
        set {
            if (value)
                m_user.loadCtrls |= ab.LoadCtrls.AtCommandStart;
            else
                m_user.loadCtrls &= ~ab.LoadCtrls.AtCommandStart;
        }
    }

    public Boolean AtProxyFound {
        get {
            return (m_user.loadCtrls & ab.LoadCtrls.AtProxyFound) != 0;
        }
        set {
            if (value)
                m_user.loadCtrls |= ab.LoadCtrls.AtProxyFound;
            else
                m_user.loadCtrls &= ~ab.LoadCtrls.AtProxyFound;
        }
    }

    public Boolean AtUserOrApplicationRequirement {
        get {
            return (m_user.loadCtrls & ab.LoadCtrls.AtUserOrApplicationRequirement) != 0;
        }
        set {
            if (value)
                m_user.loadCtrls |= ab.LoadCtrls.AtUserOrApplicationRequirement;
            else
                m_user.loadCtrls &= ~ab.LoadCtrls.AtUserOrApplicationRequirement;
        }
    }

    public Boolean NotLoad {
        get {
            return (m_user.loadCtrls & ab.LoadCtrls.NotLoad) != 0;
        }
        set {
            if (value)
                m_user.loadCtrls |= ab.LoadCtrls.NotLoad;
            else
                m_user.loadCtrls &= ~ab.LoadCtrls.NotLoad;
        }
    }

    public Boolean TransparencyLoad {
        get {
            return (m_user.loadCtrls & ab.LoadCtrls.TransparencyLoad) != 0;
        }
        set {
            if (value)
                m_user.loadCtrls |= ab.LoadCtrls.TransparencyLoad;
            else
                m_user.loadCtrls &= ~ab.LoadCtrls.TransparencyLoad;
        }
    }

}
```

Converter:

```
    public sealed class UserToUserWrapperConverter : IValueConverter {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
              return new UserWrapper((User)value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
            throw new Exception(); // never called
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<GroupBox Grid.Row="4" Header="Load this plugin, when...:" Grid.Column="0" 
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Padding="3">
    <GroupBox.DataContext>
        <Binding ElementName="lstAllUsers" Path="SelectedItem">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <local:UserToUserWrapperConverter/>
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </GroupBox.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Margin="2" Content="At proxy found" IsChecked="{Binding Path=AtProxyFound}"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="2" Content="At AutoCAD start" IsChecked="{Binding Path=AtAutoCADStart}"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="2" Content="At command start" IsChecked="{Binding Path=AtCommandStart}"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="2" Content="At user or application requirement" 
                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=AtUserOrApplicationRequirement}"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="2" Content="Not load" IsChecked="{Binding Path=NotLoad}"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="2" Content="Transparency load" IsChecked="{Binding Path=TransparencyLoad}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I not understand, how it can helps to me. Now I try to solve my problem through `IValueConverter`.

Comment: Wrap your model in the ViewModel and use it as DataContext of your View. Then bind your checkboxes to "IsAtProxyFoundSet", "IsAtAutoCADStartSet", etc. `IValueConverter` will be of no use, as you can't implement `ConvertBack`.

Comment: Yes Nicolas, the `Convert` method works, i.e. the binding from `LoadCtrls` to `CheckBox` items works fine, but I can't implement the `ConvertBack` method, i.e. the binding from `CheckBox` to `LoadCtrls` ain't working...

`Wrap your model in the ViewModel and use it as DataContext of your View.`
I learning WPF, and never did it. I will try to find info about this solution's variant.

Comment: This pattern is called "MVVM" for "Model View ViewModel" and is a key concept of WPF.

Comment: Please, look my first message "UPD" - I have updated my code. My problem still completely isn't decided. :(((

Comment: Why you added `User` item, and where definition of this class?

Comment: The `UserWrapper` not implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` - is it right?

Answer (score 0):

I use a custom checkbox and bind on 2 properties because of the dependency between the enum flag and its enum value.

This is my code (I use it in production with success and it is very simple to use - see comments on top of the class).

Do you like it ?

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace HQ.Wpf.Util.MyControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Usage: Bind on EnumFlag and Two way binding on EnumValue instead of IsChecked
    /// Example: <myControl:CheckBoxForEnumWithFlagAttribute 
    ///                 EnumValue="{Binding SimulationNatureTypeToCreateStatsCacheAtEndOfSimulation, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    ///                 EnumFlag="{x:Static Core:SimulationNatureType.LoadFlow }">Load Flow results</myControl:CheckBoxForEnumWithFlagAttribute>
    /// </summary>
    public class CheckBoxForEnumWithFlagAttribute : CheckBox
    {
        // ************************************************************************
        public static DependencyProperty EnumValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("EnumValue", typeof(object), typeof(CheckBoxForEnumWithFlagAttribute), new PropertyMetadata(EnumValueChangedCallback));

        public static DependencyProperty EnumFlagProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("EnumFlag", typeof(object), typeof(CheckBoxForEnumWithFlagAttribute), new PropertyMetadata(EnumFlagChangedCallback));

        // ************************************************************************
        public CheckBoxForEnumWithFlagAttribute()
        {
            base.Checked += CheckBoxForEnumWithFlag_Checked;
            base.Unchecked += CheckBoxForEnumWithFlag_Unchecked;
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private static void EnumValueChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        {
            var checkBoxForEnumWithFlag = dependencyObject as CheckBoxForEnumWithFlagAttribute;
            if (checkBoxForEnumWithFlag != null)
            {
                checkBoxForEnumWithFlag.RefreshCheckBoxState();
            }
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private static void EnumFlagChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        {
            var checkBoxForEnumWithFlag = dependencyObject as CheckBoxForEnumWithFlagAttribute;
            if (checkBoxForEnumWithFlag != null)
            {
                checkBoxForEnumWithFlag.RefreshCheckBoxState();
            }
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        public object EnumValue
        {
            get { return GetValue(EnumValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EnumValueProperty, value); }
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        public object EnumFlag
        {
            get { return GetValue(EnumFlagProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EnumFlagProperty, value); }
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private void RefreshCheckBoxState()
        {
            if (EnumValue != null)
            {
                if (EnumValue is Enum)
                {
                    Type underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(EnumValue.GetType());
                    dynamic valueAsInt = Convert.ChangeType(EnumValue, underlyingType);
                    dynamic flagAsInt = Convert.ChangeType(EnumFlag, underlyingType);

                    base.IsChecked = ((valueAsInt & flagAsInt) > 0);
                }
            }
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private void CheckBoxForEnumWithFlag_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RefreshEnumValue();
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        void CheckBoxForEnumWithFlag_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RefreshEnumValue();
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private void RefreshEnumValue()
        {
            if (EnumValue != null)
            {
                if (EnumValue is Enum)
                {
                    Type underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(EnumValue.GetType());
                    dynamic valueAsInt = Convert.ChangeType(EnumValue, underlyingType);
                    dynamic flagAsInt = Convert.ChangeType(EnumFlag, underlyingType);

                    dynamic newValueAsInt = valueAsInt;
                    if (base.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        newValueAsInt = valueAsInt | flagAsInt;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newValueAsInt = valueAsInt & ~flagAsInt;
                    }

                    if (newValueAsInt != valueAsInt)
                    {
                        object o = Enum.ToObject(EnumValue.GetType(), newValueAsInt);

                        EnumValue = o;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // ************************************************************************
    }
}
```